# Updating historic Ranges on Add row/column Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I Know this is pretty simple for experienced developer of Google App Script. I am new to Google App Script and trying on this since 2 days so I came here.

Let me explain the scenario, we have an Google Sheet add-on. When user do some query using our add on, we keep query id[A column], Sheet name[B column] and updated cell range[C column] in a hidden sheet as shown in image.

Now We want to update these ranges if user add/remove column/row from the sheet.

e.g we have range J4:k14 in the sheet. e.g User add column left of C, then the J4:K14 range shift to K4:L14.

```
function onChange(e) {
 if (['EDIT', 'INSERT_ROW', 'INSERT_COLUMN', 'REMOVE_ROW', 'REMOVE_COLUMN'].includes(e.changeType)) {
    
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var querySheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("OurHiddenSheet");
    // First I want to read C column to get values. that will be assigned in **range**.
    var addresses = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(querySheet.getSheetId(), range);
    // Since addresses contain all ranges, I can create RangeList from this.
    var rangeList = activeSpreadsheet.getRangeList(addresses);

    // Is there any function available in Google App Script, if the Range was impacted by the operation or not?
    

  }
}
```

How to read the entire B and C column and filter based on current sheet name and range?

I want to know, Is there any functions available to know if the range was impacted by the operation?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Now We want to update these ranges if user add/remove column/row from the sheet. e.g we have range J4:k14 in the sheet. e.g User add column left of C, then the J4:K14 range shift to K14:L14. How to read the entire B and C column and filter based on current sheet name and range?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry there is mistake. The updated range will be K4:L14. Data which was at position J4:K14, it new position will be K4:L14 due to column added at C

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I cannot still understand about your current issue of your script and your goal. Especially, I cannot image the situation from `e.g we have range J4:k14 in the sheet. e.g User add column left of C, then the J4:K14 range shift to K4:L14. How to read the entire B and C column and filter based on current sheet name and range?`.

Comment: Open a sheet
Put some data in D2:E2 range.
Add a column left to C column.
The data which we added D2:E2 range, it's new position is E2:F2 .

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `Open a sheet Put some data in D2:E2 range. Add a column left to C column. The data which we added D2:E2 range, it's new position is E2:F2 .` and your image and script.

Comment: @Tanaike The image is from sheet `OurHiddenSheet`.  Op means `NewSheet`: `Open a sheet Put some data in NewSheet!J4:K14 range. Add a column left to C column. The data which we added NewSheet!J4:K14 range, it's new position is NewSheet!K14:L14` => `OurHiddenSheet!C2` should be updated accordingly.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. Unfortunately, I cannot still image the vision of OP's goal. But when I could correctly understand it and find the different solution from the existing answers, I would like to propose it. Thank you for your  advice.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to store data as [developerMetadata](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#addDeveloperMetadata(String,String,DeveloperMetadataVisibility)). For eg, For the first row data(`NewSheet!J4:K14`), You can store metadata in row NewSheet!4:4 and column NewSheet!J:J, where `key` could be the  query uuid and `value` would be number of rows(10) and number of columns(2) respectively.

See:

- [Metadata guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata)

Comment: @ThaMaster thank you for suggesting developerMetaData, but it's limit of 30000 character will create problem for us. We are having many more data to be stored with each action user do on our add on.

Comment: @jagad89 Then just store the range references like I've shown. Store the rest in your hidden sheet. Also, It's 30k+30k per sheet

Comment: we updated our approach. When we generate any range we giving name to it. And set formulas get sheet name and range from that named range. So whenever the user do operation the namedrange get updated and it get reflected in our query log sheet.

Comment: @jagad89 Feel free to add a answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

There is no built in function that allows you to know if the range was impacted. But you can easily build a collision detector algorithm since it's a simple 2D Space:

```
/**
 * Detects the collision between to ranges specified in A1 Notation
 *
 * @param {string} a - The first range in A1 Notation.
 * @param {string} b - The second range in A1 Notation.
 *
 * @returns {boolean} - true if the two ranges overlaps false otherwise
 */
function collision(a,b) {
  var _a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(a);
  var _b = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(b);
  
  var _ax = _a.getColumn();
  var _ay = _a.getRow();
  var _awidth = _a.getLastColumn() - _ax;
  var _aheight = _a.getLastRow() - _ay;
  
  var _bx = _b.getColumn();
  var _by = _b.getRow();
  var _bwidth = _b.getLastColumn() - _bx;
  var _bheight = _b.getLastRow() - _by;
  
  return _ax < _bx + _bwidth && _ax + _awidth > _bx && _ay < _by + _bheight && _ay + _aheight > _by;
}
```

With this function you can build a `switch case` that updates your range references according to the `Event type`, overlapping and active range coordinates.

For example in the "INSERT_COLUMN" case you can update like this:

```
   var values;
   switch(e_type) {
     case "INSERT_COLUMN":
       values = querySheet.getRange("A2:C2")
                .getValues()
                .map((row) => {
                     let r = querySheet.getRange(row[2]);
                     // If the active range is outside our rangelist we don't have to update
                     if (row[1] == sheetName && range.getColumn() < r.getLastColumn()) {
                          let width = range.getLastColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
                          // When overlapping you should check where the active range start wither to offset the whole range or to extend its width.
                          if (collision(row[2], range.getA1Notation())) {
                                 if (range.getColumn() <= r.getColumn()) {
                                        row[2] = getShiftOffsetColumn(r, width);
                                 } else {
                                        row[2] = getShiftExtendedColumn(r, width);
                                 }
           
                           } else {
                                 // No collision, just offset.
                                 row[2] = getShiftOffsetColumn(r, width);
                           }
                     }
                     return row;
       });
       
       break;
     case "REMOVE_COLUMN":

       [...]
     
     default:
       // Exception handling
   }
   querySheet.getRange("A2:C2").setValues(values); //updates the values in hidden sheet

[...]

// --- Support functions ---

// This function handles the offset
function getShiftOffsetColumn(r, width) {
   return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(r.getRow(), r.getColumn() + width, r.getLastRow() - r.getRow() + 1, r.getLastColumn() - r.getColumn() + width).getA1Notation();
}

// This function handles the extension
function getShiftExtendedColumn(r, width) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(r.getRow(), r.getColumn(), r.getLastRow() - r.getRow() + 1, r.getLastColumn() - r.getColumn() + 1 + width).getA1Notation();
}
```